# Grunt integration in TFS build with deploy to Azure

Tags: azure, tfs, gruntjs

We're trying to integrate grunt in our continuous deploy process where we use tfs on-premise to build and deploy on an azure webrole.

We'd like to include grunt in the process in order to concat, uglify, etc. the javascript part.

We've already configured the build in order create a dist folder with the output generated, but we're struggling to instruct the Azure WebRole project to use this folder instead of the standard (output of the web project build included)

Has anybody experience with this quite tricky scenario?

Thanks

Comment: This is easy to accomplish if you swap out TFS to git and WebRole to WebSite. We have done this with grunt and now do this with gulp in that context. blogpost: http://www.cptloadtest.com/2013/12/03/Git-And-Grunt-Deploy-To-Windows-Azure.aspx

Comment: The problem is that I need to use WebRole in order to be able to autoscale and use a virtual network in the cloud with frontend, backend, etc. but thx for the hint!

Comment: I tried nearly everything but I haven't found a clean solution. I'll try the Dennis suggestion of using a WebSite in standard mode. In this case I'm able to configure auto scale, always on, etc. Let's see if it works